# Git check out a specific file type with LF line endings on Windows

Tags: windows, git, line-endings

On Windows, I would like to check out all linux shell files (.sh) with LF line endings

Line Endings of other text-based files should be converted to CRLF. (which is handled via the global core.autocrlf=true)

- global .gitconfig

`[core]
    editor = 'C:/Tools/Notepad++/notepad++.exe' -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin
    autocrlf = true`

- .gitattributes in repository root folder

`*.sh text eol=lf`

I used `git add --renormalize .` when adding the .gitattributes file.

Unfortunately the .sh files still have CRLF after checkout.

---

additional information: One of my team members did change his global core.autocrlf=false some commits ago, which caused the chaotic line endings, I guess.

With above mentioned steps I could at least fix files of the local repository to have CRLF endings again.

---

steps tried:

- delete files locally and checkout again: no affect - all CRLF
- delete files, push deletion, recreate files with LF: still CRLF after checkout
- manually change line endings with Notepad++...

`user@workstation MINGW64 /c/repos/project-source (bug_sh_files_eol_lf)
$ git status
   On branch bug_sh_files_eol_lf
   Your branch is up to date with 'origin/bug_sh_files_eol_lf'.
   Changes not staged for commit:
     (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
     (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
           modified:   production_code/build_production_code.sh
           modified:   test_code/unit_tests/create_unit_test_xml.sh
   no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
user@workstation MINGW64 /c/repos/project-source (bug_sh_files_eol_lf)
$ git add . -u
   warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in production_code/build_production_code.sh.
   The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
   warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in test_code/unit_tests/create_unit_test_xml.sh.
   The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
user@workstation MINGW64 /c/repos/project-source (bug_sh_files_eol_lf)
$ git status
   On branch bug_sh_files_eol_lf
   Your branch is up to date with 'origin/bug_sh_files_eol_lf'.
   nothing to commit, working tree clean
   user@workstation MINGW64 /c/repos/project-source (bug_sh_files_eol_lf)`

Comment: Simply try deleting all `*.sh` files and checking them out again to be on the safe side.

Comment: Without access to the actual repository, it is hard to be sure, but I suspect that you have existing committed copies of these `*.sh` files that have CRLF line endings in the committed version of the file. (Normally, with `core.autocrlf = true`, this wouldn't happen, but there are various ways to make it happen, after which the files *stay* that way, in commit after commit, until you change them.) **If this is the case** then the thing to do is fix the file once, manually, e.g., with `dos2unix`, add, and commit.

Comment: The add-and-commit will make a new commit in which the file has LF-only line endings, and from this point on, the `.gitattributes` entry will handle things for all *new* commits. But note: if this guess is wrong, then after using `dos2unix` or equivalent and `git add`, Git will say that there is nothing to commit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

nevermind, I had a typo in my `.gitattributes` file name

nevertheless, the solution:

- fix .gitattributes

  ```
  # normalize all introduced text files to LF line endings (recognized by git)
  *           text=auto
  # additionally declare text file types
  *.sh        text eol=lf
  *.c         text
  *.h         text
  *.txt       text
  *.yml       text
  ```
- call `git add --renormalize .` to fix line endings of files with CRLF in repository